# I am trying to render__template formatted column values (1000 separated) but its showing/repea only last or first value of the column

Tags: python, html, flask

I am expecting it to show comma separated column values in my html page rather than repeating first or last one

I am expecting it to show comma separated column values in my html page rather than repeating first or last one

Python Code:

```
@app.route('/counterpartylimits')
def counterpartylimits(): 
    climits=Cparty.query.filter(Cparty.cparty != "Select").all()

    for i in climits :
        unslimit=i.unsecuredlimit
        
        unslimit=comma_separator(unslimit)
        unslimit=unslimit

        print(unslimit)
    return render_template('climits.html',climits=climits,unslimit=unslimit)
```

html:

```
<tr>
  <td   id="id" name="id" scope="row">{{unslimit}}</th>
</tr>
```

Comment: The main goal is to render formatted column data (1000 separated numbers) to my HTML page in a tabular form. The comma_separator function does this to the column (print shows comma separated list in the console) but render templating the result ( i.e. unslimit) shows only the first value or the last value of the column in each row. Newbie me totally lost. Request for guidance, if there's an alternative way of showing front end users comma separated values fetched from db.

Comment: used .append and it worked. Thank you for visiting the question